# How to modify recipient when bouncing email in Mutt?

Tags: email, mutt

I would like to send several times the same email to different recipients. I cannot put all recipients in CC or BCC because 1. one recipient should not see emails of the others (so not CC) and 2. I have to send this email at different time according to the recipient (so not BCC).

The solution seems to be "bouncing" the email ("b" in mutt). However, when I bounce a email I just send, mutt asks me only the new recipient email. This new recipient will receive an email addressed to the first recipient and not himself. In fact, he will not see at all that the email is addressed to him.

It seems I would like to bounce emails and modify recipient. How can I do this in mutt?

Comment: Does it matter that the recipient does not see his own address in the To: line? He won't with a BCC either.

Comment: @wurtel Yes because it will reveal a email address and that this email had received previously the same mail...

Comment: If you send it initially via BCC then it won't reveal the email address. However mutt does add a `Resent-From:` header; I haven't checked whether `resend-message` as suggested by Jauncho also adds any headers. Anyway, that way (i.e. Jauncho's way) is probably the best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`resend-message` (<kbd>Esc-e</kbd>) lets you create and edit a new message based on a previous one. Just change the recipient and send.

If *several* is tens or hundreds, then make a shell/perl/whatever script to call mutt for each recipient in a database.